# Interesting question on triangular numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If **2n<sup>2</sup> + 1** or **2n<sup>2</sup> - 1**  is a perfect square say **m<sup>2</sup> = 2n<sup>2</sup> + 1** or **2n<sup>2</sup> - 1** then prove that **(mn)<sup>2</sup>** is a triangular number.

**Approach:**

I tried solving for **m<sup>2</sup>** or **n<sup>2</sup>** and tried to bring it to the required form for a triangular number, but alas was unable to do so. However, i also realised that **m** is odd and tried to substitute **m** as **2l + 1** for some l and tried solving which didn't help as well. I have verified this for **m = 3** and **n=2** which in turn gives **mn = 6** and in turn **(mn)<sup>2</sup> = 36**which indeed is a triangular number.

**PS:**

I have no idea about Pell's equation as I have seen several problems on triangular numbers being solved by Pell's equation. All the topics in which I can consider myself to have sufficient knowledge include Modular arithmetic, properties of triangular number and other basic stuff such as induction,etc..

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(mn)^2=m^2n^2=(2n^2+1)n^2=\frac{(2n^2+1)2n^2}{2}$ which is a triangular number.
Similarly you can deal with the case $m^2=2n^2-1$

Comment: ohh thanks that was a veryp easy one,silly to have messed u

Comment: messed up*, sorry fr d typo